# StopIteration error on printer.pretty(obj) when DataFrame contains nested dict & DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When storing a dictionary with a pandas dataframe inside - inside another pandas dataframe, it functions fine, BUT the pretty print fails with a glorious error (see the screenshot below).

Would love to know a workaround, or the reason it fails.

```
df_mini = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2]])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1]])
df['mydict'] = [{'bar':df_mini}]
df
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and solved.

change this line:

```
df['mydict'] = [{'bar':df_mini}]
```

to

```
df['mydict'] = [{'bar':dict(df_mini)}]
```

but if still had error try using:

```
df.loc[index , column_name]=[{'bar':dict(df_mini)}]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).